# NGINX Proxy + BIND9 issue

Tags: nginx, bind

Before finding the courage to write in here I have been reading for days to find a possible solution myself.

This is the problem. I have a NGINX Proxy manager installed on a docker container that correctly resolve the subdomain when I call them from outside my network.

I have installed a Bind9 DNS to resolve the public domain locally too.

Now this is what happen. The DNS works fine when I do nslookups 100% of the times.

If I call a subdomain that is not mapped in the proxy manager it resolves it 9 out of 10 times thanks to the wildcard directive, and send it to the standard NGINX welcome page.

If I try to resolve a domain that is actually mapped in the nginx proxy manager it fails 9 out of 10 times returning a Timeout error.

If I try to resolve things from the actual machine where everythin is installed, it works without any issue.

The problem is that there a no errors that I can find in the proxy host logs.

Does anybody knows why I am facing this problem and can point me in the right direction?

I read the bes I could the NGINX documentation, increased the number of workers to 2048.

Tried to increase the timeout values in nginx.conf